# handle cross domain ajax post in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cross-domain

My app.js has the below handler for post

```
app.all('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.options('*', cors());

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    next();
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

var whitelist = ['http://myurl.net'];

var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1; callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
    }
};
app.post('/ValidateUser/users',cors(corsOptions) , function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');

    collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });

    res.send("Hey");
});
```

The html page which calls this has the below code

```
var user = { "bla":"bla"  };

function checkUser() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/validateuser/users',
        data: user,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType:"jsonp"
        //jsonp: false,
        //jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback'
    }).success(function (data) { console.log(data) });
};
```

When i keep breakpoint and check the `req.body` , it is not having the parameters in the req.body which is undefined

I am not able to fetch the data that i am posting from the html in the node js

Comment: `error invalid credentials` sounds like a probably with your database configuration and nothing to do with the Ajax. (That said, you are trying to make a POST request with JSONP, which is impossible).

Comment: what can be done to send a data then?

Comment: Use XMLHttpRequest instead of JSONP.

Comment: Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and search for [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-withcredentials).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep 
the res.body is still not containing the data that i am sending
Not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Use body-parser module to fetch the data, for example:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./db'); //module that contains db connection config

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: __dirname });
});

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); //req.body contains the user = {bla: 'bla'} object
    var user = req.body;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    collection.find(user, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
    res.send("Hey");
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var user = { "bla":"bla"  };
    function checkUser(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function (data) { console.log(data) });
    };
    checkUser(user);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya but how can i get the data that has been sent through the post request?

Comment: thanks Konrad +1 for the sample code
Ya req.body should contain the data but it is not, since the request is cross domain i am facing some issues 
Check my updated question