# Before filter for all post requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the below code in my node.js app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
    ,cors = require('cors')
    ,app=express();
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    //some other codes
    .....
    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users );
```

If a request is made to `/users/adduser`, it will go to the `users.js` in the routes folder.

Now I want to add a filter which will capture all the POST requests and do some validations and only if the conditions are satisfied the POST should go to its handler.

I.e if i get a `/users/adduser` with a POST request, before going to the method in the users.js in the routes folder, I should be able to capture that request and stop it if the condition is not met.

**UPDATE 1**
Now i am having this app.use function, but in the result i am getting undefined as its not waiting till the function is returning value

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.db = db;
    if (req.method != "POST") {
        next();
    }
    else {
        var userData = req.body;
        var result = Check(userData);
        if(result){
        next();            
        }
    }
});

function Check(userdata) { 

    var url = "someurl"+userdata.Id;

    var request = require("request");
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            if (response.toJSON().body.id == userId) { 
                return true;
                // i also tried next();
            }  
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: do you use express? absolutely not clear what is `app`

Comment: Which kind of condition you should check?

Comment: @simon thanks have edited the question
yes i am using express

Comment: @Edgar I am checking for permissions and stuff before post is  made

Comment: Using the middlewares will be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a simple middleware function for that:

```
var validator = function(req, res, next) {
  // If the request wasn't a POST request, pass along to the next handler immediately.
  if (req.method !== 'POST') return next();

  // Perform your validations.
  Check(req.body, function(err) {
    // Validation failed, or an error occurred during the external request.
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(400);
    // Validation passed.
    return next();
  });
};

function Check(userdata, callback) { 
  var url     = "someurl"+userdata.Id;
  var request = require("request");
  request({ url: url, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      if (response.toJSON().body.id === userId) { 
        return callback(null, true);
      }
    }
    return callback(new Error());
  })
};
```

You have various points at which you can insert this middleware, which kind of depend on how exactly your app is structured.

One option:

```
app.use('/users', validator, users);
```

Or, if you have a separate router for `/users` (in `./routes/users.js`):

```
router.use(validator);
```

Or, if you have a separate `POST` route for `/users/adduser`:

```
router.post('/adduser', validator, function(req, res) { ... });
```

In the last case you don't have to check `req.method` in the validator middleware because it's limited to the `POST` handler anyway.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep
Please check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701893/handle-cross-domain-ajax-post-in-node-js

Comment: I am making a request to server to check user is authorized, but before the data is returned it is going to the next step as javascript runs asynchronously

Comment: @vignesh you need to call `next()` (or `res.sendStatus()`) only after your async request has completed.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with code, please check . Not sure where to call the next()

Comment: @vignesh I edited my answer to incorporate your `Check()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a route middleware assuming you use Express.

If you want to perform validations for all `POST` requests to `/users` then you can add the following middleware before the route handler:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (your request is valid){
      next();
  } else {
      //Return a response immediately
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Bad request" });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check(userdata) running asycn so you should use callback here :D

```
function Check(userdata,cb) { 

    var url = "someurl"+userdata.Id;

    var request = require("request");
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            if (response.toJSON().body.id == userId) { 
               cb(null,true);
            }  
        }
    })
};
```

Then change the middleware like

```
    var result = Check(userData,function(err,result){
            if(result){
                next();            
            }

}
```